# I want to migrate a Magento site to a new url that is on the same server

Tags: magento-1.9, migration

I have a Magento site on xyz.com and want to transfer it to abc.com on the same server, nothing is changing but the branding and the url. Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance, sorry for the n00bness

Mat

Comment: So you will not be changing anything but the URL?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have database access, and I sure hope so, you might want to use this query to update your Unsecure and Secure URL's:

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = 'http://yournewdomain.com/'
WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url'
LIMIT 1 ;
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = 'https://yournewdomain.com/'
WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url'
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that you are not changing the server you can do this in two simple steps

- You need to point the new domain - new.com to the folder with your magento site. You can do it in the cpanel.
- Now you need to change the URL for your magento website inside the database. You can do it in phpmyadmin by going to core_config_data table in your database and changing the values for web/unsecure/base_url to http://new.com and web/secure/base_url to https://new.com if you are using SSL or to http://new.com if not

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from admin panel

login to `admin panel`

got to `system->configuration`

open the `Web tab`

change the `base url` in `Unsecure` and `Secure`

and delete the `var/cache` folder.